Is there a way to persist a contact ID and checksum from an event info page to a registration page?
One of the orgs I support is using CiviEvent finally after years of using other aspects of Civi. It works pretty well and though the event info pages are basic, they serve well enough that we are using them rather than build something else.
The cid and checksum tokens work well if we are sending people directly to a registration page, but in many cases we are sending them to the event info page first so they can see the details before they register.
The problem is, even if we send them to the event info page with cid and checksum set in the URL, it doesn't make it through to the registration page when they click the register button on the info page.
Is there a way around this that either sets up some kind of session so they are able to continue to various pages as themselves, or at least passes the values through to the registration page?

That sounds like a good feature request.
Update: It's been added to CiviCRM 5.78: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30998

Will reach out on Mattermost.
